# Search for videos outside "My Videos" folder using Video lens

Tags: unity, video, lenses

My remote scope for the video lens has the following:

- YouTube Movies
- TED Talks
- ??some chinese characters??
- Encuentro
- RTVE
- 3sat Mediathek
- YouTube Education
- VODO
- SCI-FI London
- YouTube Shows
- Vimeo
- Bing Video
- Dailymotion

There is no normal Youtube, does anyone know why this is the case?

When searching for videos locally, it searches the "My Videos" directory. I believe
this is hardcoded correct? I tried adding in a symbolic link inside My Videos to
an external fat32 drive but the lens didn't search it. Is there any way to make
this work?

*EDIT* symlink following is listed as a feature in progress: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-videos/+bug/934589

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is hard-coded `FOLDER = GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.USER_DIRECTORY_VIDEOS)`.  It is still in python though so you could change it by editing `/usr/lib/unity-lens-video/unity-lens-video`